# replace count (CASE WHEN) in this query

Tags: mysql

i m want to replace CASE WHEN in this query

```
SELECT label ,date,count(id) AS nb, count(CASE WHEN label='test' THEN 1 END) AS nb_test
    FROM
    sil_test,sil_data
    WHERE
    sil_test.id_t=sil_data.id_t
    GROUP BY
    label, date
```

any idea??

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version of this query that works with MySQL:

```
SELECT label ,date,count(id) AS nb, sum(label = 'test') AS nb_test
FROM sil_test join
     sil_data
     on sil_test.id_t = sil_data.id_t
GROUP BY label, date;
```

I'm not sure what problem this solves, except for replacing ANSI standard syntax with MySQL-specific functionality.  And, of course, fixing the joins so they are explicit (much, much, much recommended).

Comment: WHERE  sil_test.id_t=sil_data.id_t not 
WHERE  sil_data.id_t=sil_data.id_t